# Obtener las 3 ciudades distintas con más ventas

Tags: sql

Buenas tengo este query

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito que la salida sea con las 3 ciudades distintas con más ventas, pero no me sirvió ya que la salida me genera los 3 campos con más ventas de una misma ciudad.

Adjunto imagen de salida.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté poder un distinct antes de la primera columna a.city pero no me funcionó. Alguna sugerencia.

Si le quito el top3 al inicio del query la salida sale así para que se den una idea porque es que lo quiero con las 3 ciudades distintas con más ventas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Entendiendo que estás en Access, te sugiero crear otra consulta como la que propones pero quitando el segundo campo del `GROUP BY` para obtener las 3 ciudades más ventas.

Una vez tengas esta consulta, tendrás que hacer un `INNER JOIN` con la original sin el `TOP 3`, y así obtendrás las 3 ciudades con más ventas y su desglose en `Categoria`.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Hola gracias por responder es en sql Server, lo que no entendí es como crear la otra consulta que dices y unirla con la original, perdón por la ignorancia

Comment: Utilizando subconsultas `SELECT * FROM (subconsulta) AS c1`

Comment: Supondrá que en esa subconsulta se agrega el distinct)

Comment: No te hace falta el `DISTINCT` si estás haciendo un `GROUP BY`